# Leaflet - How do I make islands appear over my sea surface temperature data?

Tags: leaflet

How do I make islands appear on my map?  They are covered by my temperature data.  I am having trouble finding a guide for this specific task.

Here is my code

```html
<html>

<style>
#map{ width: 1000px; height: 600px; }
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.1/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-coverage@0.7.2/leaflet-coverage.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.1/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/covutils@0.6.1/covutils-lite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/covjson-reader/0.16.3/covjson-reader.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-coverage@0.7.2/leaflet-coverage.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

<script>
var map = L.map(document.getElementById('map'), { center: [10, 0], zoom: 2 })
//var myStyle = {"color": "#ff7800", "weight": 5, "opacity": 0.65};
//L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map)
L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Ocean_Basemap/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {attribution: 'Tiles © Esri — Sources: GEBCO, NOAA, CHS, OSU, UNH, CSUMB, National Geographic, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, and Esri'}).addTo(map);


var layers = L.control.layers(null, null, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map)

var layer
CovJSON.read('coverage.covjson').then(function (coverage) {
  layer = C.dataLayer(coverage, {parameter: 'sst'})
    .on('afterAdd', function () {
      C.legend(layer).addTo(map)
      map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds())
    })
    .addTo(map)
  layers.addOverlay(layer, 'sst')
})

map.on('click', function (e) {
  new C.DraggableValuePopup({
    layers: [layer]
  }).setLatLng(e.latlng).openOn(map)
})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is what the map looks like with the data.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this with a similar problem, I found a decent solution that can be done in about 10 minutes.  It is not optimal, but it works.  I ended up print screening a google maps image of the islands since it resembled the background.  I loaded this up in paint to clean up the picture (remove land).  From there, I uploaded the file in power point (paint doesn't have transparency tool) in order to make the water transparent.  I then added this image as a new layer on top after getting the coordinates of the print screen from google maps in order to geo reference the image.

```
var imageUrl = 'islands.png',
    imageBounds = [[32.801608, -120.450498], [34.076603, -118.305885]];
L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```